# why format list in tinymce RTE is empty in umbraco?

Tags: tinymce, umbraco7, rte

in my umbraco system when i try to create a content in RichTextbox format list is empty as below picture:
[image: empty Formats List]

I have searched in google and found [this](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-4578#tab=Comments) issue on umbraco issue tracker and do its guide line but there was no result. how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you set up a stylesheet like shown here? http://umbraco.tv/videos/umbraco-v7/implementor/fundamentals/stylesheets-and-javascript/setting-up-rte-styles/documentation

Comment: yes i add but still this dropdown menu is empty 8O

Comment: i try another time this and it fill the dropdown but when i try to use, it never change the style of my content.

Comment: Did it at least update the HTML? You still have to include the stylesheet in your template for it to work on the frontend.

Comment: no it did not make any difference in any where.

Comment: if you are experienced in umbraco please check this thread too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42109556/1093228

Answer (score 3):

1. Login to umbraco backoffice and go to Settings>Stylesheets section and create a rte style sheet with all the css classes in it.
2. Add a new rte.css class to your umbraco solution's css folder if there isn'T one already and update the css classes according to your values in umbraco backoffice.
3. Go to Developer>DateTypes and select SimpleRTE and in the Stylesheets section, check rte as your stylesheet.
4. The in your content page, you will see the formats list as shown below.
5. Please see screen shots for more details. Hope it helps.

[image: I have created screenshots to explain how you can make it work.]

Comment: i test it... this add items to my menu but when i click on this items no change have been done :(

Comment: I have just added a new css and it works fine: If I choose Table row (blue) from the dropdown, it changes the background color of the text. Remember to highlight the text first and choose the css from the dropdown!  Name: Table row (blue) Alias: .tableRowBlue  Styles: background-color: #D2EEF4;